# Bootstrap 3 container width broken when in mobile resolution

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/sodacrunch/pen/oXbQeB)**

Start from a full window, and the shrink it. It goes through 3 media queries. As you can see with the first 2, the container maintains its style, but when it snaps to the last media query, mobile mode, the container becomes full width and no overscroll functionality. How is this happening?

The only way I can get this to work is a way that makes no sense to me, by giving a width, doesnt matter the size:

```
 .product-location-scroll {
    width: 10px;
}
```

This is the section I am referencing:

```
<div class="product-location-scroll-container">
<div class="product-location-scroll">
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Johns Creek</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            9775 Medlock Bridge Road
            <br>Johns Creek, GA 30097
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0599</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Brookhaven</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            4060 Peachtree Road
            <br>Brookhaven, GA 30319
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0580</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Sandy Springs</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            6309 Roswell Road
            <br>Sandy Springs, GA 30328
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0581</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Dunwoody</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            2482 Jett Ferry Road
            <br>Dunwoody, GA 30338
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0582</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Johns Creek</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            9775 Medlock Bridge Road
            <br>Johns Creek, GA 30097
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0599</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Johns Creek</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            9775 Medlock Bridge Road
            <br>Johns Creek, GA 30097
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0599</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-location">
        <p class="product-location-place">Johns Creek</p>
        <p class="product-location-address">
            9775 Medlock Bridge Road
            <br>Johns Creek, GA 30097
        </p>
        <p class="product-location-phone">(678) 686-0599</p>
        <p class="product-location-hours">
            Open Daily
            <br>
            <b>10:00 AM to 8:00 PM</b>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="product-location-select">Select this location</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this out, if not for all sizes, at least for < 768px:

```
.wrapper {
      display: table;
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdGemE?editors=110)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from this rule:

```
.product-location-scroll-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The .product-location-scroll is inheriting it, which is preventing the box resizing to the viewport.